# Разные шаблоны страниц для товаров

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в woocommerce сделать, например, 2 разных шаблона для 2-х товаров? То есть, есть 2 товара, я хочу один товар выводить в отдельном шаблоне, второй товар - в отдельном. На данный момент создал кастомный шаблон, привязал его к странице (через Свойства страницы -> шаблон), в шаблоне подтянул объект продукта через id и на этой странице вывожу его свойства - тут вроде все ок, но застрял на стадии перелинковки на странице Витрина магазина (стр. где выводятся превью всех товаров). Суть в том, что когда кликаешь по какому-то из этих превью, то тебя перебрасывает на страницу со стандартным шаблоном товара от woocommerce, а мне надо, чтобы оно кидало на мой кастомный шаблон...

Подскажите плз, это возможно как-то сделать? Если да, то подтолкните, если можно).

Спасибо

P.S. Думал сделать редирект 301 или через wp_redirect... но, может, есть другой путь, так как этот не сильно надежный...

Comment: Я  в репо видел готовые плагины для подобного. Названий не помню,

Answer (score 1):

Скопируйте `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` в папку `wp-content/themes/моя-тема/woocommerce/`.

Проверяйте в этом шаблоне `$product->id` и делайте вывод контента товара так, как вам нужно.